# How can i cut a lot of repetitive code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I posted a few times about a project I have in AS3 (a dynamic map of Europe between Roman Times and now), and I'm still learning as I go.

I'm making this sort of list of names (buttons) that opens a biography when clicked. 
In the example.fla I linked you'll find the fraction of my code I have trouble with. It works the way it is but I have over 500 bios and I'd like to know if there is another way, less repetitive.

Here's the code :

```
var char_array_rom: Array = [auguste, tibere];
var textes_array: Array = [hero, life, short, comment, pop, photo];

close_bio_btn.visible = false;

for each(var char: MovieClip in char_array_rom) {
char.visible = false;
};

//___________________________________________________________________//

/* Close Kings Bio */

close_bio_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_close_bio);
function fl_close_bio(MouseEvent: Event): void {
close_bio_btn.visible = false;
for each(var texte: TextField in textes_array) {
    texte.visible = false;
};
for each(var char: MovieClip in char_array_rom) {
    char.visible = false;
};
};

//____________________________________________________________________//


/*Rome*/

/* A */

/*Auguste*/
auguste_list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_auguste);
function fl_auguste(MouseEvent: Event): void {
close_bio_btn.visible = true;
auguste.visible = true;
for each(var texte: TextField in textes_array) {
    texte.visible = true;
}
};

/* T */

/*Tibère*/
tibere_list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_tibere);
function fl_tibere(MouseEvent: Event): void {
close_bio_btn.visible = true;
tibere.visible = true;
for each(var texte: TextField in textes_array) {
    texte.visible = true;
}
};
```

Do I have to copy/paste/adapt the ligns about the characters over and over or is there an another way to do this? Thanks.

If you want to see the code in action I've made this example.fla for the occasion ;)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndpa920u0mg2pbs/example.fla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Event::target` property to determine which hero list element has been clicked, then you should have either a `Dictionary` or two arrays or any kind of relation structure that will hold association data between list element and hero. Then you get that relation based on `e.target`, retrieve corresponding hero and also get corresponding text data. Since you have a list of heroes already, you might decide to make a corresponding list of those `someHero_list` movie clips, so that the element at index 0 corresponds to a hero of index 0, etc etc. Like this:

```
var char_array: Array = [auguste, tibere, louis_xiv, angela_merkel, henry_viii];
// etc, you can use one array for such a thing
var list_array:Array = [auguste_list, tibere_list, louis_xiv_list, angela_merkel_list, henry_viii_list];
// etc, make sure each list element stands at the same index as the referring hero
var visibleHero:MovieClip=auguste; // initialize with non-null just in case
for each (var aList:MovieClip in list_array) 
    aList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showHero);
closeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hideHero);
function showHero(e:Event):void {
    var listElement:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject; // get which list was clicked
    var i:int = list_array.indexOf(listElement); 
    if (i<0) {
        trace('ListElement not found:',listElement.name,'using current target!');
        listElement = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
        if (listElement) i = list_array.indexOf(listElement); 
    }
    trace(listElement.name,i); // debug only
    if (i<0) return; // oops, not found!
    visibleHero = char_array[i]; // the hero from the other array is the one we need to show!
    visibleHero.visible=true; // now show the hero...
    for each(var texte: TextField in textes_array) {
        texte.visible = true;
    } // ... and the text fields...
    closeButton.visible=true; // ... and the button...
    ... // [TODO] ... and fill the text fields with data taken from hero.
}
function hideHero(e:Event):void {
    visibleHero.visible=false; // hide the hero...
    for each(var texte: TextField in textes_array) {
        texte.visible = false;
    } // ... and the text fields...
    closeButton.visible=false; // ... and the button
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast and well explained answer! I'll try your method monday morning (or sooner if I can) and will come back to validate your answer :)

Comment: I had an free hour so I tried it, and I got that error: "1118: Contrainte implicite d'une valeur du type statique Object vers un type peut-être sans rapport flash.display:DisplayObject.". I looked it up and apparently adding a "as DisplayObject" after "e.target" fixed it (i don't know if it was good but it disappeared. I also go a second error: "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." This one I think i know why: the mc in list_array are mc inside mc (letter_a.auguste_liste). I havent figured how to fix it yet, i'll try when i have more time. will b back :)

Comment: It should be possible to write `letter_a.auguste_liste` in place of `auguste_liste`, since you precisely know how to get that reference.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it still doesn't work. I'll recheck all the mc in list_array to be sure I didn't make a mistake or forgot one of them.

Comment: The night was short but I found the problem: my buttons are written in french 'auguste_liste' and i wrote in english in the code 'auguste_list' . What a noob! The error 1009 is dead :). But when I click on the buttons, nothing happens. I tried copy/pasting your code so i make no mistakes, and still the error 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.displayisplayObject. at line 'var listElement:DisplayObject = e.target; // get which list was clicked'. If i add 'as DisplayObject' after 'target' the error disappears but the buttons don't work.

Comment: Put `trace(listElement.name,i)` before `if (i<0) return;` Most likely the target is some wrapper over `auguste_list` instead of that one.

Comment: Here is the result of the trace: instance5578 -1   I have absolutely no idea what it means. I'm really sorry to be such a noob, it is my first real project. So thank you for your patience, i really appreciate it!

Comment: (the number of the instance is different on each button)

Comment: This means the `e.target` is different from those listed in your `list_array`. Then, try doing this: (updating answer in 5...4...3...)

Comment: Updated answer. This searches for `e.currentTarget` in the list, as well as for `e.target`. Most likely some nested element of your label is interactive and is the target instead of what we need, so we are using another property to get the instance to which the listener is attached. Sometimes it's better to use target, say if you have ONE listener for a big object, but here it doesn't seem to work, but we have many listeners attached.

Comment: It works perfectly and you've become one of my favorite internet people :). Even though it is not much, i'll make sure to thank you in the part of the app where i thank people that helped.